# Anti-aliasing custom bar button image in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, custom-controls, uibarbuttonitem, antialiasing

I'm trying to use a custom bar button image. I've created a simple PNG image with a white object and a transparent background as [recommended by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW8):

[image]

As you can see, there is no anti-aliasing being applied (that is my exact image, pixel for pixel).

Apple does recommend to use Anti-aliasing, but don't provide any more detail. I would have thought this would be a function of the software like it would with text, rather than pre-applying it to the image.

The question is--how can I programatically provide anti-aliasing for my custom bar button images?

I have tried several things but nothing is doing it for me. Here's one thing I tried:

```
- (UIImage *)antialiasedImage
{
    // Check to see if Antialiased Image has already been initialized
    if (_antialiasedImage != nil) {
        return _antialiasedImage;
    }

    // Get Device Scale
    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

    // Get the Image from Resource
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ReferenceFieldIcon"]; // .png???

    // Get the CGImage from UIImage
    CGImageRef imageRef = [buttonImage CGImage];

    // Find width and height
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);



    // Begin Context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(buttonImage.size, YES, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Set Antialiasing Parameters
    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, YES);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, YES);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);

    // Draw Image Ref on Context
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);

    // End Context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();



    // Set CGImage to UIImage
    _antialiasedImage =
    [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

    // Release Image Ref
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);



    return _antialiasedImage;
}
```

Then I create my Segmented Control Like So:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    NSArray *centerItemsArray =
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:  @"S",
                                self.antialiasedImage,
                                @"D",
                                nil];


    UISegmentedControl *centerSegCtrl =
    [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:centerItemsArray];

    centerSegCtrl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;


    UIBarButtonItem *centerButtonItem =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:(UIView *)centerSegCtrl];


    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                  target:nil
                                                  action:nil];




    NSArray *barArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:  flexibleSpace,
                                                    centerButtonItem,
                                                    flexibleSpace,
                                                    nil];

    [self setToolbarItems:barArray];
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IOS doesn't add anti-aliasing to rendered images--only items drawn from code. You'll have to anti-alias the image before saving to file.

The way to anti-alias images from code is to draw them code.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm very surprised there it's not possible to provide the mask and have iOS do the dirty work of antialiasing and adding the bevel. Oh well.

Comment: Is it possible to draw an existing .PNG "from code"? Say I had a larger version of the Icon, 200x200 for instance. Would it be possible to programatically scale it down to 40x40 and apply interpolation to make it appear anti-aliased?

Comment: Yes, that is possible and something iOS does automatically.